# What is the correct form of address for a police officer?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

How should one address a police officer in English speaking countries? More specifically, in a non-emergency situation—asking directions for example—what is the expected form of address used to call a police officer's attention?

Comment: My own experience has left me confused: In both the US and the UK I recently had occasion to ask for directions from police officers, both of whom happened to be sergeants. In the UK, "sergeant" was clearly accepted (the officer was polite, and very helpful) while in the US I fear this was not the correct appellation (the officer was surly and confrontational).

Comment: coincidence I suspect. The American officer was just a surly character. Or in a bad mood. Or at the end of his shift...

Comment: Did you call accidentally someone *sergeant* who had a different rank than that? That might have put them off if they were actually of a higher rank, but that’s no excuse for being surly. Maybe the American officer was just in a bad mood. BTW, it’s something of a military thing to call someone by their rank, which has spilt over into the constabulary. Outside situations like the military and such, we nearly never use titles anymore in regular English, at least, not compared with the Germans.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, quite certain (and as mentioned below, I've had similar experience using _"officer"_).

Comment: American police officers can sometimes be like French waiters. Hard to find when you need them, and rude when you have found them. But "sir" always works with the men.

Comment: I've personally had pretty bad results with ociffer, but YMMV.

Comment: "Officer" is the typical address in the US for a uniformed officer.  For a plain-clothes detective, "Officer" will probably irritate them and "Detective" is the appropriate address.  If you know enough to recognize their rank insignia, addressing them as "sergeant" or "lieutenant" or whatever would also be acceptable, but using the wrong rank might put them off.

Comment: FWIW, I've experimented with this a bit (and asked a few officers directly where, where I could get away with it) and "officer" works fine, though in most situations a form of address isn't really needed (it ends up seeming overly formal). There is in fact a big difference between the US and the UK, but, as I've since learned, that has less to do with the form of address and more to do with different "theories of policing": in the UK they have something called "policing by consent" while in the US, police are "quasi-military". This make US police generally more standoffish than in the UK.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Use "Officer" unless his car has the word "Sheriff" on it, in which case, use "Deputee". If he takes offense at following this rule of thumb, he's a jerk and there's not much you can do to avoid offending a jerk who's looking for a reason to get offended.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are all officers of the law, so "*officer*" applies no matter what their rank ("Pardon me, officer...").

Comment: Yes, I've tried _"officer"_ as well, but have had similar results, so I'm wondering whether I'm not doing something wrong in the US.

Comment: Either he was having a bad day, or perhaps he's simply a jerk. Unprofessional behavior in any case.

Comment: I suppose if he was just promoted to captain after a long hard struggle, he might be frustrated that you called him "sergeant". But really, unless you're calling him "pig" or something, I don't see why he should be offended. I once visited a college campus where the security guards had recently been officially designated police officers by the state, and not really thinking about it I referred to their building as the "security office". One of them forcefully informed me that it was a "police station". I guess they took being real-live police officers instead of rent-a-cops very seriously.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You might not be doing anything wrong, and even if you were, you might not be aware of what it could be.  But I doubt it's because you used "officer" to address a police officer.

Comment: I've had "state troopers" be very offended by calling them "officer" instead of "trooper".

Comment: @corsiKa That does not sound reasonable to me.

Comment: @tchrist I completely agree. Apparently, they don't office, they troop! I would just be glad that someone is making an honest attempt at civility, if it were me.

Answer (score 11):

I've lived in Britain all my life, and I don't think I would use any particular word to address a policeman. It's seldom necessary to use an appellation in a typical British conversation. Indeed, it would seem odd.

In the US, people seem to like calling each other "Sir" and "Ma'am" as a mark of respect, and I see no reason why that wouldn't be appropriate with a police officer.

If you must use an occupation-specific appellation, then you can use the person's rank. But that requires you to recognise their badges, or you risk getting the rank wrong. AS @Gnawme observes, "officer" is always OK.

Any policeman worth their salt, of course, will treat you politely whatever you call them (unless you abuse them).

Comment: I'm not sure what circles you go in, but 'madam' is __never__ used to address any one on AmE  (except maybe specific instances like addressing someone under parliamentary circumstances with a title 'Madam President' or 'Madam you Honor').

Comment: I think you mean *maam*, not *madam*. It’s *yes sir* and *no maam.*  A waiter at a very very very snooty restaurant might perhaps say *Madam, may I take your coat?* But sir/maam are kinda put-offish, too. Southerners do this with their parents; being a Northerner, my mom once said she thought she’d burst out and cry if one of her kids called her *maam*.  It’d be like *vous*-ing or *Usted*-ing your parents, which might happen in France but not in Spain. It is a cold, distancing thing. This is one of the North/South cultural distinctions.

Comment: @Mitch: I have to agree. I certainly cannot imagine a situation where addressing a US police officer as "sir" or "ma'am" wouldn't seem quite odd.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: nothing is simple. I'd say there would be a tendency (in AmE) to use 'sir' or 'ma'am' in response to an officer (and almost always in Southern AmE: "Yes, sir, officer").

Comment: @tchrist: the emotional reaction depends on how native it is - it might sound cold/distancing for non-speakers, but for native speakers it's probably a sign of respect..

Comment: @Mitch: That _must_ be regional: I don't think the phrase "yes, sir, officer" has been uttered here in New England since the Civil War.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius One is taught ***always*** to address an officer of the law as *sir* or *maam* as appropriate for their sex. It would be considered rude not to do so — and being rude to a police officer is **always** a really bad idea.

Comment: I agree that "madam" is pretty much out of date. But "sir" and "ma'am" are very common words for addressing people whose names you do not know, regardless of their occupation or status. In the place I've lived, anyway, which means the Mid-Atlantic and Mid-West. The stereotypical salesman's query is, "Can I help you, sir?" People often say things like, "Excuse me, ma'am, you dropped your cell phone." Etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone; I updated "madam" to "ma'am". In my head, it was just a pronunciation thing.

Comment: @tchrist I thought parents were the archetypal figures you should always *vous*. In Welsh, it's certainly *chi* for parents, teachers, policemen etc. and *ti* for friends. Maybe Spanish is different.

Comment: @slim No, you never Usted your parents in Spanish. It would make strangers out of them, as though you started calling them Mr&Mrs Smith instead of Mom&Dad.  In the same way, you always address the deity as ‘tu’, also. You are on intimate not formal terms with them.

Comment: @tchrist surely that depends on the deity!

Comment: @tchrist, depends on the country. In Spain you scarcely ever use usted; in Colombia, you use usted with almost everyone, including your parents.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, ask. This sort of thing does vary from one region to another. When you find yourself in a new place and you're not sure what the local custom is, there's nothing wrong with asking politely: *Excuse me... I'm new to this area. How should I address a police officer such as yourself?*

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the harm in calling them 'constable'.

Comment: You must come from a different country than I do or else enjoy strange looks.  ;-)

Comment: The latter.  In the US, its use might ensure their attention.  :)

Comment: If you're going to do that in the US, at least fake an English accent.

Comment: constable was the way to go once upon a time

Answer (score 1):

In Japan, we adress police officer just casually as “Omawari-san" meaning "Mr. (Ms) police (officer),” though I’m afraid I’d be laughed at when I did so in UK and US.

Comment: No, you wouldn't be laughed at. I think that that is a reasonable thing to do. I have done similarly. Police, like most people, will respond more favorably if using Mr. or Ms. if there is uncertainty. If you don't know the individual's name (one needs to stand very close to read name tags), this can happen. I do that with all public servants i.e. government employees. Mr. Mailman, for example, when trying to get the attention of someone. It is cautious, but you will not offend. Mr. Police officer or man or woman acknowledges their official status as officers of the law.

Comment: "Mr. policeman" sounds overly condescending to my ears. I'd certainly love to see someone addressing a policeman like that.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a neutral "mister/miss/comrade policeman/policewoman".

Comment: Comrade Policeman? You some kinda Commie, bud?

Comment: Comrade Policewoman??

Comment: @Daniel δ why not? http://www.nydailynews.com/archives/news/decoy-casey-jones-chapter-208-article-1.499754?pgno=1

Comment: That's not used as a form of address, that's a description of the other policewoman's relation to her. Just as "fellow worker" is fine (*my fellow workers are great!*), but it would not be normal to say "Fellow worker, could you come over here?"  Plus, *comrade* is the wrong relation.  To illustrate, the article you just referenced uses it as a term describing the relation of one police officer to another officer of essentially similar position, and in that case it cannot properly be used between a civilian and a police officer.

Comment: @Daniel δ no. If it was saying "...and her comrade, policewomen Gertrude Schimmel..." then it would clearly mean a fellow worker. But it says "...and comrade policewoman Gertrude Schimmel..." similar to "...and miss policewoman Gertrude Schimmel...", "...and mister chairman John Smith..."